# Matching numbers to mask it

Tags: unix, awk, match, mask

I have a text file like below. It's a position-based text file. The positions from 13 to 30 represent bank account numbers and need to be masked with an asterisk if a number exists. What's the best way to do this? My OS is Oracle Solaris 11.4

```
6220750000610032002137       0000404584               MCKENNES JAITLIN C      0071000280000122
622075000079643811983        0000420000               RICHOTTA AMENDA         0071000240000134
632275079784326217002        0000340000               KOHLDECK CARA           0071000230000146
622101205691399004002904006210000610000               MEIER NICHOLAS          0071000270000222
```

Expected Outcome

```
622075000061**********       0000404584               MCKENNES JAITLIN C      0071000280000122
622075000079*********        0000420000               RICHOTTA AMENDA         0071000240000134
632275079784*********        0000340000               KOHLDECK CARA           0071000230000146
622101205691*****************0000610000               MEIER NICHOLAS          0071000270000222
```

I am trying the below command but getting an error.

```
gawk '{if (match($0, "[0-9]", 13, 27)) $0 = substr($0, 1, 12) "*" substr($0, 27)}' PAY.EM

gawk: cmd. line:1: {if (match($0, "[0-9]", 13, 27)) $0 = substr($0, 1, 12) "*" substr($0, 27)}
gawk: cmd. line:1:  

                         ^ 4 is invalid as number of arguments for match
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you make it `622075000061*****************0000404584` instead of leaving spaces: `622075000061**********       0000404584`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @jared_mamrot comments, it may be difficult to define the 'best'. Here is a posix-compliant solution just for information:

```
awk '{s = substr($0, 13, 17); gsub(/[0-9]/, "*", s); print(substr($0, 1, 12) s substr($0, 30))}' PAY.EM
```

Result:

```
622075000061**********       0000404584               MCKENNES JAITLIN C      0071000280000122
622075000079*********        0000420000               RICHOTTA AMENDA         0071000240000134
632275079784*********        0000340000               KOHLDECK CARA           0071000230000146
622101205691*****************0000610000               MEIER NICHOLAS          0071000270000222
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk (which I see in your error messages like `gawk: cmd. line:1:  ...` you are already using) for `FIELDWIDTHS`:

```
$ gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='12 17 *' -v OFS= '{gsub(/[0-9]/,"*",$2); print}' file
622075000061**********       0000404584               MCKENNES JAITLIN C      0071000280000122
622075000079*********        0000420000               RICHOTTA AMENDA         0071000240000134
632275079784*********        0000340000               KOHLDECK CARA           0071000230000146
622101205691*****************0000610000               MEIER NICHOLAS          0071000270000222
```

If you have an old version of gawk that doesn't support `*` as the final part of `FIELDWIDTHS` to read the rest of the line then use `FIELDWIDTHS='12 17 99999'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

How do you define 'best'? Assuming a fixed-width file format, one potential option using GNU AWK (not posix) would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS = "29 26 25 17"
}

{
    a = substr($1, 1, 12)
    b = substr($1, 13, 30)
    gsub("[[:digit:]]", "*", b)
    print a b $2 $3 $4
}' test.txt
622075000061**********       0000404584               MCKENNES JAITLIN C      0071000280000122
622075000079*********        0000420000               RICHOTTA AMENDA         0071000240000134
632275079784*********        0000340000               KOHLDECK CARA           0071000230000146
622101205691*****************0000610000               MEIER NICHOLAS          0071000270000222
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The output is as below. 
`62207500006100320021370000404584MCKENNESJAITLIN`
`6220750000796438119830000420000RICHOTTAAMENDA`
`6322750797843262170020000340000KOHLDECKCARA`
`622101205691399004002904006210000610000MEIERNICHOLAS0071000270000222`

Comment: Ahh, yep - looks like Oracle Solaris 11.4 comes with POSIX awk, not GNU awk - sorry @Dito, I'll come up with a POSIX alternative

Comment: no problem, tshiono provided it already which works!

Comment: Yep, @tshiono's answer is how I would approach it, glad you solved your problem

Comment: AFAIK the awks on Solaris aren't even POSIX compliant. /bin/awk (aka oawk) is simply broken and should never be used while between nawk and /usr/xpg[46]/awk once of them doesn't support character classes (e.g. `[[:space:]]`) while the other doesn't support regexp intervals (e.g. `{5}`). But it's been 7 years or so since I last used Solaris so maybe things have changed. If anyone knows, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk

```
$ awk -v from=13 -v to=30 -v mask="*" '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}
    {
     for(i=from;i<to;i++) $i=($i==" " ? $i : mask)
    }1
' file 
622075000061**********       0000404584               MCKENNES JAITLIN C      0071000280000122
622075000079*********        0000420000               RICHOTTA AMENDA         0071000240000134
632275079784*********        0000340000               KOHLDECK CARA           0071000230000146
622101205691*****************0000610000               MEIER NICHOLAS          0071000270000222
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk or some other awk that will split into characters given a null FS. It's undefined behavior per POSIX so different awks will do different things with it.